# How to invert numbers in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset with answers from a scale from 1 to 7. However I'd like to invert some of the responses in a quick and easy way for multiple columns, so that 1 becomes a 7 and 2 becomes a 6.

```
x <- sample(c(1:7),147,replace=TRUE)


rescale <- function(x_i){7-x_i}
```

This isn't working as I intended.

The recode function from the car package is actually changing the variables. But I'm not quite sure if I'm using this function correctly and if this is the best method in general to do this.

```
car::recode(cleandataframe$x, '1=7; 2=6; 3=5; 4=4')
```

Is there any other common way to inverse easily multiple columns like this? Is there a solution without the car package?

Comment: 8 - x? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Roland I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make factor -> Solution 1. or keep numeric -> solution 2.

**Solution 1**

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(c(1:7),147,replace=TRUE)

x <- factor(x)
levels(x) <- rev(levels(x))
x
```

this vector:

```
   [1] 1 7 4 1 5 4 2 7 1 1 4 2 1 6 3 7 2 2 7 7 2 1 5 2 6 6 6 5 1 4 6 5 7 2 6 6 2 7
 [39] 5 5 6 6 7 1 5 3 5 7 2 3 6 4 4 1 7 2 6 5 2 6 5 1 3 7 6 6 1 6 2 5 3 4 6 4 4 2
 [77] 2 6 6 5 3 7 1 4 7 6 6 1 3 3 7 5 5 7 6 7 3 7 4 1 2 1 1 6 2 4 6 1 5 6 2 5 3 2
[115] 1 4 2 3 3 1 1 1 6 4 4 2 7 4 7 3 1 5 6 2 6 3 2 1 2 4 5 6 6 6 2 1 2
```

to output:

```
[1] 7 1 4 7 3 4 6 1 7 7 4 6 7 2 5 1 6 6 1 1 6 7 3 6 2 2 2 3 7 4 2 3 1 6 2 2 6 1
 [39] 3 3 2 2 1 7 3 5 3 1 6 5 2 4 4 7 1 6 2 3 6 2 3 7 5 1 2 2 7 2 6 3 5 4 2 4 4 6
 [77] 6 2 2 3 5 1 7 4 1 2 2 7 5 5 1 3 3 1 2 1 5 1 4 7 6 7 7 2 6 4 2 7 3 2 6 3 5 6
[115] 7 4 6 5 5 7 7 7 2 4 4 6 1 4 1 5 7 3 2 6 2 5 6 7 6 4 3 2 2 2 6 7 6
Levels: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Solution 2**

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(c(1:7),147,replace=TRUE)

(max(x, na.rm=T) + 1) - x
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask such a stupid question but what does y represent?

Comment: Sorry not intended. Just workflow. See my edit. There is no stupid question at all!

Comment: It is actually not giving me the right inverse numbers. I tried with two different columns. my variables are numeric. Is there anything i forgot? I copy pasted the code.

Comment: `set.seed(123)
x <- sample(c(1:7),147,replace=TRUE)
original_x <- x

inverse_x <- (max(x, na.rm=T) + 1) - x

original_x
inverse_x`